# Zsh pipe all output to command

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, file-descriptor

In Zsh, I know you can do `command &> file.txt` to pipe *all* file descriptors to file.txt (rather than having to do each file descriptor individually like `command 2>&1 3>&1 > file.txt` if you had three file descriptors).  Is there a way to pipe all file descriptors to another command? such as `command <mystery operator> cat`?

Edit: I was wrong, as Chepner and Etan pointed out; `&>` only redirects fd's 1 and 2.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `&>` redirects more than just standard output and standard error? I would find that surprising and the docs don't seem to indicate that behavior that I can see

Comment: Note that `cmd 2>&1 > file.txt` does not actually redirect stderr (file descriptor 2) to the file.  But `cmd > file.txt 2>&1` does.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`&>` only redirects standard output and standard error, not all file descriptors that `command` might write to. The equivalent pipe, though, is

```
command |& grep  # Equivalent to command 2>&1 | grep
```